# почему при нажатии на кнопку удалить, показывает ошибку Cannot GET /abonent/2/remove

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const express = require('express'),
    mysql2 = require('mysql2/promise'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    nodePath = require('path');

const pool = mysql2.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'task2',
    password: '',
});

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/styles.css', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/styles.css');
});

const nav = ({ path }) => `<ul>
    <li>${path == '/' ? '<span>Cписок студентов</span>' : '<a href="/">Cписок студентов</a>'}</li>
</ul>`;

function loadPages(pages) {
    pages.forEach(it => {
        const [_, method] = nodePath.parse(it).name.split('@');
        const [path, action] = require('./pages/' + it);
        app[method](path, async (req, res) => {
            const result = await action(pool, req);
            if (typeof result == 'function') {
                result(res);
            } else {
                res.send('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css"/></head><body><nav>' + nav(req) + '</nav><main>' + result + '</main></body></html>');
            }
        });
    });
}

const listOfPages = fs.readdirSync('./pages');

loadPages(listOfPages);

app.listen(3000, function() { 
    console.log('server started at', this.address().port); 
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav, main {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

main {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    gap: 5px;
}

nav > ul > li > a, nav > ul > li > span {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}

nav > ul > li > span {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
}

h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

h1 > form {
    margin-left: 7px;
    display: flex;
}

h1 > button {
    margin-left: 7px;
}

button > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.error {
    color: red;
}
```

```js
module.exports = ['/add-abonent', async function (pool, { query, body }) {
    return `
        <h1>Добавление студента</h1>
        <form method="post" action="/add-abonent">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Имя студента" minLength="2" name="name"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Фамилия студента" minLength="2" name="lastname"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Отчество студента" minLength="2" name="dadname"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Группа студента" minLength="2" name="clas"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Дата рождения" name="datee"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить"/>
        </form>
    `;
}];
```

```js
module.exports = ['/add-abonent', async function (pool, { body }) {
    const { name, lastname, dadname, clas, datee} = body;
    await pool.query('INSERT INTO abonents SET ?', {
        name, lastname, dadname, clas, datee,
    });
    return res => res.redirect('/');
}];
```

```js
module.exports = ['/', async function (pool, { params, body }) {
    const [abonents] = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM abonents');
    return `
        <h1>Список студентов</h1>
        <ul>
            ${abonents.map(abonent => `<li><p="${abonent.id}">${abonent.name} - ${abonent.lastname} - ${abonent.dadname} - ${abonent.clas}
             <a href="/abonent/${abonent.id}/remove">Удалить</a></p></li>`).join('')}
        </ul>
        <button><a href="/add-abonent">Добавить студента</a></button>
    `;
}];
```

```js
module.exports = ["/abonent/:abonent_id/remove", async function (pool, { params }) {
    const { abonent_id } = params;
        await pool.query('DELETE FROM abonents WHERE id = ?', abonent_id);
}];
```

Comment: А ваш route что-то вернул?

Comment: Я как понял, у меня ошибка в путях, скорее всего я как то не правильно синтаксис указываю или что-то забыл, но не могу понять что

Comment: Любой другой роут работает?

Comment: всё работает, кроме кнопки "Удалить", я думаю вам будет удобнее просто самому код запустить, я скинул весь код, который у меня есть, ну если вам не сложно конечно

Comment: Я просто не вижу, как вы используете код, который экспортируете.

Comment: Что конкретно не понятно?